# How to check the density of a set?

Tags: general-topology

> How to check the density of a set ?
>
> I have to prove that a metric space with a countable basis is separable,
>
> $\text{separability is defined like}$: a metric space is dense if it has a sequence
>   $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, which is dense in $X$
>
> $\text{density is defined like}$: $\forall x\in X$, $\exists$ a subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{n_k}$ of $(x_n)_n$ s.t. , $d(x_{n_k},x)\to0$

I already proved the other direction, but now if we have a countable base, say $\{w_n:n\ge 1\}$, then every open set in $X$ can be written as a subset of this base and then we have to construct a dense subset, whose closure is $X$ right ?

What is the role of the sequence here ?

Comment: could you please state more precisely the what is the implication that you need to prove?

Comment: @user126154 metric space has countable basis$\Rightarrow $it is separable.

Comment: The tag "measure-theory" means something else, so I removed it.

Comment: @Gedgar actually it was an exercise from measure theory and integration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $U_n$ be the countable basis. For each $n$, choose $x_n\in U_n$. If $\{x_n\}$ is not dense, then its complement has non-empty interior. Hence there is some $U_i$ that do not intersect $\{x_n\}$. Contradiction.

Comment: aha, nice answer, so every $U_n$ must be ''used''.

Comment: @derivative: yes, exactly!

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ bet the countable dense set you identified and let $S'=\{B(x;r):x\in S,p\in\mathbb{Q}\}$. This is countable since it's the cross product of countable sets and since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $S$ is dense in $X$, we are done.

For the other direction, let $\{B_n\}$ be a countable base. By the axiom of choice we can pick one element, $x_n$, from every $B_n$. This sequence is countable since it's in bijection with the base. It's dense because it intersects every open set - $B_n$ is a basis so every open set contains at least one $B_n$ and each $B_n$ contains at least one $x_n$.

Comment: I used a similar proof for the other direction.